# Laravel > nested eager load with restriction

Tags: laravel, eager-loading

Assumed we've got users, friends and restaurants. Don't want to go to deep into the Model and relationship setup.

While me as a user is logged in: How can I get all friends who are "customers" of the restaurant?

I've got this and it's already working:

```
$friends = array_dot(Auth::user()->friends()->select('users.id')->get());

$customers = Restaurant::with(['users' => function($query) use($friends) {
    $query->whereIn('users.id', $friends);
}])->find(restaurant_id);
```

But is this even possible with a single query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to find all of your friends that have a relationship to the restaurant. If so, you're looking for `whereHas()`. General idea:

```
$restaurantId = 1;
$user = Auth::user();

$friendCustomers = $user->friends()->whereHas('restaurant', function ($query) use ($restaurantId) {
    $query->where('id', $restaurant_id);
})->get();
```

You can read more about querying relations, and `whereHas`, [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations).